# creating subdomains on the fly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I can see lots of hosted SAAS applications nowadays giving subdomains for their users, like if an app (say project management tool) is http://myapp.com and if a customers can have subdomains like

http://customer1.myapp.com , http://customer2.myapp.com and these urls can be reserved when the user is registering with the application.

I have a re-seller hosting plan and I want to the same thing, and my hosting plan has set wildcard subdomain and technically I can create any subdomain under my main domain. But my question is

with ruby/ rails

- How to allow customers to pick their subdoamin by the time their
  registration
- what is the standard approach for a requirement like this

I'm planning to use rails 3.x.x

thanks in advance

Comment: I know this is an old question but it will be helpful to post if you found any solution for people like me facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I just recently did something similar, and what I did is that I configured the server to accept any subdomain and then redirect to a resource url.  In your case, you will probably just route that subdomain request to the rails server.  If you're using nginx, you would have something like:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  dev.yoursite.com *.dev.yoursite.com;
    root /path_to_your_site/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env development;
}
```

Then, in your app you can create a route with a subdomain constraint,
something along the lines of `get '/' => 'users', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }`, and handle that subdomain in your controller action using `request.subdomain` to find a matching user.

Keep in mind, that in your local environment, either list all your subdomain for testing or use `lvh.me` instead in your server config.  If you will be using your own domain instead of lvh.me, don't forget to add that domain and subdomain in your hosts file. Also, for prod, don't forget to add wildcard subdomain record in your DNS.